# Xml duplicate node detection in webapi c#

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have created a webapi project to accept both JSON/XML.
I want to check the XML/JSON response contains repeated value.
But currently webapi omits the second occurance automatically omitted.i want get exception or error.Same in JSON also.

```
Sample Input
<ClassA>
<item1>AA</item1>
<item1>BB</item1>
</ClassA>

Actual result:
NO exception ignore second occurrence

Excepted result:
get exception for second occurance or error
```

Comment: For the Json part at least, do you mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35796738/6017401)?

Comment: Yes for JSON also@ChrisS