# How can i force an exception to be thrown when user passing duplicate field in json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

If i am accessing the api through postman and try to modify the json by passing duplicate field(ex:- FirstName) then it's giving the success response. The api is taking the 2nd duplicate field and update the value.

**Model Class:**

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First Name should be length of 1 - 50")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Last name should be length of 1 - 50")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "User Name should be length of 1 - 50")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string AdminFirstName { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string AdminLastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PrimaryEmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string SecondaryEmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string ManagerEmailAddress { get; set; }
        public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Here is my post webapi which i am accessing through postman.

**PostAPI:**

```
[HttpPut]
 public ActionResult EditUser([FromBody] UserDTO userInfo, [FromQuery(Name = "adminUserId")] Guid adminUserId)
        {
            StringValues clientConnectionString;
            try
            {
                
                   _userDA = new UserDA();
                    var result = _userDA.EditUser(userInfo, adminUserId, clientConnectionString);
                        if (result.ReturnValue == -1)
                        {
                            return BadRequest(new ErrorResponseDTO()
                            {
                                MessageCode = _messageCodePrefix + result.Result,
                                ErrorType = "Bad Request",
                                RequestId = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier.ToString()
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Ok(new StatusInfoDTO()
                            {
                                MessageCode = _messageCodePrefix + result.Result,
                                RequestId = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier.ToString(),
                                ReturnValue = result.ReturnValue,
                                Status = "Success"

                            });
                        }
                    
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogCritical(ex.ToString());
                return StatusCode(500, new ErrorResponseDTO()
                {
                    MessageCode = "Inernal server error",
                    RequestId = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier.ToString(),
                    ErrorType = "Bad Request"
                });
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom JsonConverter which throws an exception when encounters to a duplicated key.

Install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/8.0.0-preview.3.23177.8) Nuget Package and register it:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Then create a custom JsonConverter:

```
public class CustomJsonConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var paths = new HashSet<string>();
        existingValue = existingValue ?? Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, true);

        var backup = new StringWriter();

        using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(backup))
            do
            {
                writer.WriteToken(reader.TokenType, reader.Value);

                if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
                    continue;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Path))
                    continue;

                if (paths.Contains(reader.Path))
                    throw new Exception("The "+reader.Path+" field is duplicated!");

                paths.Add(reader.Path);
            }
            while (reader.Read());

        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(backup.ToString(), existingValue);
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And decorate your model using this converter:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))]
public class UserDTO {}
```

Test Result:
[image]

The answer quoted from [user3473830's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35796738/18789859).